# How Black Star was influenced by the Kishin's hallucinations?

Tags: soul-eater

Caution: contains spoilers.

> In episode 23, when Black☆Star approach to Eruka he was under an illusion. When it comes to the sixth sense (soul wavelengths), Black☆Star admitted he immune to the effects of the Madness. So why when he use the Enchanted Sword he was affected by the madness illusions?

Comment: Where exactly is it said that he is immune to Madness? I can't seem to find it...

Comment: in this [wiki](http://souleater.wikia.com/wiki/Black%E2%98%86Star).
"Black Star, however, replies that he has a dull sixth sense, and thus will not feel the madness."

Comment: Ok, found it. Expect the answer soon :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, it took me some time to find it. You are referring to this:

> [image]

Knowing what kind of person Black☆Star is, I wouldn't take his statement neither too seriously nor too literally.

It is known that it is possible to overcome madness if one has bravity and a strong heart. Black☆Star definitely has those. In fact, it is shown in the *Baba Yaga's Castle* mini-arc (if you excuse me for calling it a "mini-arc"), that Black☆Start indeed is capable of overcoming Madness, at least to some point. Note that in that mini-arc, after Black☆Star encourages the other characters, they are able to overcome Madness as well after hardening their minds.

We also know that later Black☆Star

> gets the ability to use Madness Release (Hakkyou, 発狂) changing his Wavelength to one of Madness.

However, according to the same [wiki](http://souleater.wikia.com/wiki/Black%E2%98%86Star) that you referenced, even he has a possibility of slipping into Madness if he uses this ability for too long. It is also stated [here](http://souleater.wikia.com/wiki/Madness) that the stronger the Madness Wavelength, the harder it is to overcome Madness.

Considering the above, another important note is that in Baba Yaga's Castle mini-arc, Black☆Star was rather far away from the source of Madness, while in the episode you mention he was *right near* it; more than that, the source was kishin himself.

So I think that while Black☆Star indeed has some sort of resistance to Madness, his statement in that episode was partly bragging, partly overestimating himself and underestimating the enemy, which eventually let him susceptible to the (quite powerfull themselves) illusions.

Comment: If the stronger the wavelength, the harder to withstand the madness.
How come "death" himself didn't overwhelmed by it?
After all, he has the most powerfull wavelength.

Comment: @Hashirama, you mean Death the Kid in the same episode? He was caught in the hallucination right when he entered the kishin room (that's in chapter 21 of the manga), but managed to realize that was a hallucination after some time

Comment: No no, I mean THE "Death" (his father).

Comment: @Hashirama, how is Shinigami related to this exact episode? Nevertheless, Shinigami is arguably the most powerful character in the series, so he should definitely be able to withstand kishin's madness. He has also already faced and beaten kishin before.

Comment: The Shinigami related to the first comment (refer to the first sentence I wrote).

Comment: @Hashirama, ahhh! I think I have misunderstood your first comment! By saying "the stronger the wavelength, the harder to withstand the madness" I was meaning Madness Wavelength, not any Wavelength at all. Shinigami should probably have Anti-Demon Wavelength type, I think. I'll fix the question to remove this ambiguity.

Comment: Very well, I accept.